# Cannot save element inside axios

Tags: javascript, axios

```
function getMovie(){
  let movieId = storage.getItem('movieId');
  var title = "";
  axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + movieId + "?api_key=...." + "&language=en")
  .then(function (e) {
    let movie = e.data;
    title = movie.title;
    console.log(title); //frist
  })
  console.log(title); //second
}
```

Only the first one displays on the console, the second one does not. I would like to display both of them.

Comment: the code doesnt work  sequential as you expect here. the second log will not wait until the first one finishes. in that case you will need to use async await

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoRJizFvM7s

Comment: thanks, now that is working